# Blazor, is there a way to terminate rendering partway through render?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a schedule page with several periods on it.  If I select a period, it will show the editing page for that period rather than the other markup on the schedule page.  What I want is something like:

```
@if (selectedPeriod is not null){
   <EditPeriod Period=selectedPeriod />
   return;
}
<div>
     . . . All the other stuff on the page, which should not be rendered if editing.
</div>
```

Where `return` would terminate the rest of the render, so that all the other stuff after it wouldn't be rendered.  The page markup is pretty long, and I dislike the idea of putting the main body of the page in a giant `else {}` block.

Comment: No, your only options would be control blocks (if / else) and using sub components.

Comment: Yes you can the compiler is seeing your `return;` as markup...

Comment: @BrianParker are you sure?  I actually just tried it and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RenderFragments are delegates of course you can.

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
@{
    return; 
}
Welcome to your new app.
```

Comment: Hmmmm. . . I'm wondering if I can drop all those ugly `else` blocks and use this as my default way of terminating the render.  I often do that in C# code.

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate Brian's answer, this Razor code block:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

@if(true)
{
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    return;
}

Welcome to your new app.
```

Is compiled into:

```
//..
if(true)
{
    __builder.AddMarkupContent(3, "<h1>Hello, world!</h1>");
    return;
}
__builder.AddMarkupContent(4, "\r\nWelcome to your new app.\r\n");
//..
```

Comment: Given a complex page, what do you think of returning out of the render as a substitute for `if / else` blocks?

Comment: I'm a firm believer in the modern approach to methods where you exit early and avoid `else` unless you really need to.   I use it all the time in standard methods, but hadn't thought to use it in markup as you propose.  I will now where appropriate.  In complex pages I now often split out code into separate `RenderFragments`, so the main markup compiled into `BuildRenderTree` is just high level code.

Comment: It never occurred to me either, until I was going to have to put a huge page of markup in an `else` block, just so I could optionally show an editor window.  Such a gross abuse that would have been!